# Emulate file uploading forms with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data

I dynamically generate svg markup on client side and convert it to a data-url for downloading purposes. This procedure works fine and generates a valid svg file.

Besides I have a Java Servlet which takes an uploaded svg file and converts it to pdf. When I take a downloaded svg file from above and upload it through a standard HTML form this Servlet works absolutely fine.

I just want to combine those two parts by sending the generated svg without even saving it before. I already tried to send the data as base64 string like that:

```
 reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
 reader.onloadend = function() {
    base64data = reader.result;                
    console.log(base64data );
    form['data'].value = base64data;
    form.submit();
  }
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Are there any ways of emulating a file upload with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FormData object:

```js
$('form').submit(function(){
  
  /**** creating blob object 
  .....
  ****/
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    base64data = reader.result;
    
    var fd = new FormData(this);
    fd.append('file', base64data, 'file_data'); // field_data - "Optional" param, it means The filename reported to the server
    fd.append('other_field', fieldvalue);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/upload.php',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, this tries to solve the problem using ajax. But I can't save the pdf from ajax response. I need to actually open the new page.

Comment: in which way do you save pdf at this moment?

Comment: The reponse of my servlet is a pdf file stream. Therefore the browser automatically opens/saves the file.

Comment: you want to receive pdf steam, reserve it, and then invoke open/save pdf file dialog  in new window by request(demand) ?

Comment: This would be one possibility. Otherwise it would be totally fine to submit the base64 data via POST to the servlet and simply open the result page.

Comment: have you tried this code in .done function: window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data); or var blob = new Blob(data, { type: "application/pdf;base64" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); window.open(url);

Comment: Thanks for this hint, it actually opened a PDF file (another step accomplished) but this file is still completely empty. There seems to be an error during fhe file upload :-/

Comment: filesize limits on server-side is OK ?

Comment: okay, I checked the pdf files in my ide: In contrast to the original file output  this generated output has several unrecognized characters. This might be an encoding error of my PDF results.